# cx freeze module not correctly installed

Tags: pandas, numpy, operating-system, cx-freeze

so i have a python file that imports another python file to run it. works perfectly.
Then i would want to convert it to an exe file. after serveral attempts i got it to run and call in its packages as an import another python file that only does a easy gui prompt. then i do the same putting prompts back and forth after imports such as os, pandas and numpy. it doesnt work :(. no prompts at all not even the beginning.

```
<i>
    includefiles =["listofratios.txt"]# ["1991/","1992/","1993/","1994/","CSV/","CSV2/","wave/","histodistro/","histograms/","rangerover/","rangerover3/","limwindspeed1.txt","limwindspeed2.txt","limwindspeed3.txt","limwindspeed4.txt","limwindspeed5.txt","limwindspeed6.txt","limwindspeed7.txt","limwindspeed8.txt","limwindspeed9.txt","windspeed1.txt","windspeed2.txt","windspeed3.txt","windspeed4.txt","windspeed5.txt","windspeed6.txt","windspeed7.txt","windspeed8.txt","windspeed9.txt","listofratios.txt","punjabi.txt"]


includes = ["a12roguewavewindspeedrelater","a11roguewaveprobabilityperinstantsimulated","a10wavesimulation","a9finddistribution","a8rayleighchecker","a7correlationchecker","a6CSVnorthseareorganizer","a5CSVreorganizer","a4onlynorthseadata","a3onlywaterdata","a2dataCSVsorter","a1datadownloader","a13testrun"]#"random","Tkinter","ftplib","xray","xarray","_subprocess","easygui","math","pandas","os","numpy","fitter","matplotlib","a12roguewavewindspeedrelater","a11roguewaveprobabilityperinstantsimulated","a10wavesimulation","a9finddistribution","a8rayleighchecker","a7correlationchecker","a6CSVnorthseareorganizer","a5CSVreorganizer","a4onlynorthseadata","a3onlywaterdata","a2dataCSVsorter","a1datadownloader","a13testrun"]
excludes = []#"Tkinter"]
packages = []
base = None# "Win32GUI"
setup(
    name = 'waves.exe',
    version = '1.0',
    description = 'waves',
    author = 'name',
    options = {'build_exe': {'includes':includes,'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}}, 
    executables = [Executable('a0projectinterface.py',base=base)]
)</i>
```

Comment: Have you considered pyinstaller?

Comment: wow pyinstaller is amazing! thankyou @Simons123